# Who is using the Plutus Application Backend (PAB) here in this forum?

Tags: discussion

My last three questions all concerned the PAB and have received no answers. This got me wondering if anyone in this forum is actively using the PAB and if so, how he/she is using it.

This is more a community survey than a question, but I think it would be very helpful to know how people here think about this. So if you are using the PAB or considering using it, please let the forum know how your experience has been so far. What has been working, what issues did/do you have ? How could others in this forum help you ?

I, on my side, am following the examples of the Plutus git repository. I could launch endpoints in the PAB simulator and make some transactions work that only involved the known wallets of the simulator. I am now trying to export a transaction from the PAB to pass it to the Nami wallet for the user to sign it. This is were I am currently struggling.

Comment: I’m struggling with the same thing. I’ve gotten comfortable with the simulator but my workflow doesn’t feel translatable to working on the testnet/mainnet. I’ve figured I just need to wait for better support. The cli doesn’t make for a good development flow.

Comment: I haven't tried with the CLI. I don't think it is worth the effort. I just got one step further in this moment as I could solve my serialisation issue. I have the feeling that I am quite close to a solution for integrating an external wallet. The thing that is difficult is that all examples are shown with contracts directly submitting the transaction. I think a first step is to add for all these contracts a contract that returns an 'ExportTx'.

Comment: Moving to [meta]

Answer (score 1):

There a number of possible reasons why there are no responses to questions about the PAB.

1. Nobody with the answer is here
2. The question is not encouraging a response
3. Those that could answer the question no longer come here because their efforts are not rewarded (their answers not upvoted and/or marked as accepted)
4. So few users have looked at the tour or the help center that the site is destined to fail at building into a useful database of questions and answers

Searching this site for PAB questions shows that many of the short, well explained, targeted questions are being answered.

> [How can I get a fully built transaction from the PAB](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/q/6188/281) was long, confusing and
> vague.  It seemed like the poster wanted somebody to write a tutorial for
> them.  I believe it would be much more likely to be answered if it followed
> the guidelines in [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

If this community does not establish a culture of informing new users, adhering to the guidelines and supporting each other then it will never be as good as the Stack Exchange sites for the other cryptocurrencies ([Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/), [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/), [Tezos](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/), etc.)

Comment: Are you kidding me ? "How can I get a fully built transaction from the PAB" could be answered by one sentence or one line of code. I referred to my open issue on the Nami GitHub, which is very informative, to get more background. My issue even made it into the official Cardano documentation (see section "Browser wallet": https://plutus-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plutus/explanations/pab.html).

Comment: Could the question simply be...  "The only way to implement smart contracts is to hand over a fully built transaction to the wallet. When using the PAB, the Contract instance needs to build it using the wallet address (and optionally a pre-defined UTxO for the collateral) of the user. I haven't seen any code showing how to achieve this in the GitHub repository. How can this be done ?"   The first two paragraphs as they are currently written _seem_ superfluous to me.  It may well be answered with a short response, but the question didn't give me that impression.  Different for a Plutus dev?

Comment: BTW - Good work getting your issue into the official Cardano docs.

Comment: This formulation would miss the point that this question is making: handing over an unbalanced transaction to the wallet is the way that the Cardano developer team has defined as the standard and only way to interact with the wallet using the PAB. Apparently they did not notice that this is not possible with current wallets. This question gives a nuanced take on this approach and asks for an alternative. I don’t see a need to dumb it down.

Comment: OK, it didn't make that point clearly to me but your comment did (might say more about me than the question).  Thanks for the clarification.  Hopefully someone will answer it.